# Simple way to read select lines from a file

Tags: c#

There are 100 Lines in my .txt file. This code will read every line, Line by line. How do I change the outcome to only read line 3, line 4, and line 5 respectively?

```
string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Horoscope\iso_8859-1.txt");

        foreach (string line in lines)
        {
            // Use a tab to indent each line of the file.
            Console.WriteLine("\t" + line);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [System.IO.StreamReader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/file-system/how-to-read-a-text-file-one-line-at-a-time) to read the file line by line

```
int counter = 1;  
string line;  

// Read the file line by line.  
System.IO.StreamReader file =
    new System.IO.StreamReader(@"C:\Horoscope\iso_8859-1.txt");  
while((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)  
{  
    if(counter > 5)
    {
        // No need to continue
        break;
    } 
    else if(counter >= 3)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine(line);
    }
    counter++;  
}  
file.Close();
```